# How to stop a click function running immediately but still pass an index?

Tags: javascript

When I call a function from another function via a click event everything work OK:

```
const func2 = () => {
  console.log('this ran')
}
const func1 = (item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', func2);
}
```

However when I pass an index then the second function (func2) runs immediately.

```
const func2 = (i) => {
  console.log(i + ' was clicked')
}
const func1 = (item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', func2(i));
}
```

Comment: Either use a wrapper function or bind your arguments.

Comment: the documentation clearly explains how to do this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
const func2 = (i, event) => {
  console.log(i + ' was clicked');
};

const func1 = (item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', func2.bind(null, i));
};
```

Since arrow functions do not have their own context (the `this`), passing `null` ensures that you don't expect `func2()` to have access to any particular context. The `event` will be "pushed" to the next argument, as indicated by `func2 = (i, event) => { ... }`.

#### Alternatively, use a wrapper function:

```
const func2 = (i, event) => {
  console.log(i + ' was clicked');
};

const func1 = (item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => func2(i, event));
};
```

Assuming you understand how scoping works, this simply creates an anonymous callback function that has access to both `i` and `event` in its scope, passing them in whatever order you prefer to `func2()`.